Can I update value of the private member in another package by using Java encapsulation concept?
Input:
Name:
PAN:
Phone:
Account_no=987452
For all users account no should be updated in increasing order.
I tried encapsulation concept
Getter and setter method
And taken all input from the users
But got stuck while I was trying to update account no.
